# Docker access localhost

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I have docker running and I want to access my mongodb on port 27017
so I do something like this:

```
const hapiMongooseOptions = {
    bluebird: false,
    uri: 'mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017'
};
```

How should I reference the localhost like my real machine? what IP I should use?

(PS. this is not working, I think the problem is with IP)

**EDIT**

I start docker by `$ bash deploy.sh` which looks like this:

```
 sudo docker stop soho-api
 sudo docker rm soho-api
 sudo docker stop soho-db
 sudo docker rm soho-db
 sudo docker rmi soho-api:0.1
 sudo docker-compose build
 sudo docker-compose up -d
```

This is my `docker-compose.yml`

```
version: "2"
services:
  soho-api:
    build: .
    image: soho-api:0.1
    container_name: soho-api
    environment:
      NODE_ENV: development
    ports:
      - "3001:3001"
    volumes:
      - ./src:/app/src
    links:
      - db
  db:
    image: mongo:3.4.1
    volumes:
      - ./data/mongodb/db:/data/db
    ports:
      - "27017:27017"
    container_name: soho-db
```

and this is my `Dockerfile`:

```
# create a file named Dockerfile
FROM node:7.4.0-alpine

RUN mkdir /app
WORKDIR /app

COPY package.json /app
RUN npm install
RUN npm install -g lab

COPY . /app

EXPOSE 3001

CMD ["npm", "start"]
```

Comment: How did you start the docker container?

Comment: @AndreasWederbrand I've updated the question

Comment: Well @durisvk that edit is useless -- you'll need to show the contents of the compose file. What OS are you using?

Comment: I am using Ubuntu 14.04

Comment: @mustaccio I've updated the question

Comment: Also, reference from where? From another container (presumably the one running node? From host? Did you consider reading the Docker networking documentation?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you try to access it from outside the containers in docker-compose your code looks correct, you should be able to access it on `127.0.0.1:27017`.

If you try to access it from inside the containers in docker-compose you need to change your code.

Containers in docker-compose can reach each other by name, in your case your mongo-db is accessible using `mongdb://db:27017`

There is excellent information in the [docs](https://docs.docker.com/compose/networking/)